# Converting from a mainframe packed decimal number to an integer in C#

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I've spent the better part of a week and finally figured out how to convert packed data from the mainframe into a hexadecimal number representation.  Now, I am trying to figure out how to get that hexadecimal string into an integer in Visual C#.  I'm sure there's an easy function for this, but it's bypassing my searches at the moment.  Here's the code that is giving me the mainframe representation:

```
// Get the packed decimal field from the input record
String testString = dataRecord.Substring(40, 4);
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(testString);
// Create two different encodings.
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
Encoding ebcdic = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
// Unpack Data
Byte[] bt = Encoding.Convert(ascii, ebcdic, bytes);
// Get the data into a string in the format of 00-5F (represents a positive 5)
// The format of 00-5D (represents a negative 5)
String numberString = BitConverter.ToString(bt);
```

If the mainframe decimal value is 5, bt[0] ends up being 00, and bt[1] ends up being 5F.  After converting to a string, I end up with "00-5F".  What I really want to have, is an integer or string that just says "5".  I could just write my own thing to test every digit, and return the correct value, but I'm thinking there has to be a way to convert from a hexidecimal signed number to a string or integer without having to write a routine of my own.  Does anyone have any ideas what the function might be?  I've tried the standard convert.toint, todecimal, etc. functions but they get freaked out by this format.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  If I never received an answer to a question, should I remove the question?

Comment: Never mind, I see how it works now.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Have you tried `short.TryParse` with `NumberStyles.HexNumber`? You'd still have to do little manipulation on it, but it's a start.